# How to set Responsive padding/margin

Tags: html, css

I want to code my website from psd. I see there, that paddings/margins etc. are in pixels unit. 
What unit I should using to responsive web?

Comment: `rem`, `em`, `vw`, `vh` google these units, you'll get your answer.

Comment: Did you try googling this first?

Answer (score 0):

For the responsive way you shuold use percentage But many time we have to use pixel for example like container and other element. Suppose we want fixed a element width then we have to use pixel Because pixel unite is not flexible.